# Query select method in CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring

Tengo estas dos clases con una relacion muchos a muchos:

```
public class Planta {

    public Planta() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "belongs_to",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name="planta_id")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="sensor_id")}
    )
    private Set<Sensor> sensores;

    ...
}

public class Sensor {
    public Sensor() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;  

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="sensores")
    private Set<Planta> plantas;

    ...
}
```

Lo que necesito es un método que me devuelva los sensores que tiene una planta que le paso por parametro.
Tengo esto pero no funciona:

```
@Query("SELECT s.nombre from Sensor s JOIN s.sensores Planta")
List<Sensor> findAllByNombre(@Param("nombre") String nombre);
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que no no lo sepas, para hacer uso de queries con JPA no se usa SQL sino [JPQL](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL). Esto significa que la sintaxis de los queries cambia un poquito.

El primer problema con tu metodo que busca sensores en la base de datos, es que estas indicandole explicitamente que use el comando para hacer el query a la BD. Al haber hecho esto, no se armara un query dinamicamente basandose en el nombre del metodo, por lo que tu el resultado de tu metodo sera un simple `SELECT` con `JOIN` sin `WHERE`.

El segundo problema, es que tu query no es correcto. Especificamente en esta parte `JOIN s.sensores Planta` estas diciendo que tu entidad `Sensor` tiene un campo llamado `sensores` que llamaras `Planta`. No solo no existe, sino que creo que has confundido la intencion de tu query.

Tercero, no es aparente que quieres que responda tu query. Si solo observas la firma, sabes que respondera una `List`, pero de que? Y tu query especifica que la respuesta es `s.nombre`, osea el nombre del sensor y no el sensor en si como dices en tu pregunta. Es conveniente que especifiques que sera una lista de `String`, si lo que buscabas era los nombres de los sensores, asi:

```
List<String> findAllByNombre(...);
```

Si resolvemos todos estos asuntos, y tus entidades estan correcamente configuradas, algo como esto deberia funcionarte:

```
@Query("SELECT s.name FROM Sensor s JOIN s.plantas p WHERE p.nombre = :name")
List<String> nombreDeSensoresPorNombreDePlanta(@Param("nombre") String nombre);
```

Answer (score 0):

La consulta tal y como está escrita está pidiendo el nombre del sensor (aparte de que de error de sintaxis), por lo que devolvería una lista de strings con todos los nombres de los sensores.

El HQL sería algo como:

```
select s
from Planta p join p.sensores s
where p.nombre = :nombre
```